# Getting Labels of id's

Tags: php, mysql, database, kohana, database-performance

What is the best way to get labels of id's .

Here is the problem i'm facing .

I have a many tables that only contains id's (subject_id , level_id , place_id , etc..)

What is the best way to display the labels of those id's without making a complex sql query when displaying (have minimum of 6'ids) ?

The other options which is not very nice to do would be to call get_label(id,table,lang)

but of course you can see the problem for each column  (Total queries = column * rows)

Any better solution or i'm stuck without doing the join on 6 tables ?

If it's helps i'm using kohana

here is what i have ...

[image]

and the subject table for the subject_id :

[image]

I have for every field_id a table that correspond .

In term of performance which is better making a join or just calling a query to get the specific label when needed . ?

Comment: What do you mean by an id's "*label*"?

Comment: modified my question ... so instead of getting (subject_id = 3) i would get (Chemistry)

Comment: But that data is only in the subject table... so of course you will have to join with the subject table to get it!

Comment: Yes I think you are "stuck" with a join, but the overhead on that should be little to none IMO.

Comment: How big are translation tables? Would it be possible to cache them in memory?

Comment: i can't cache them , because they might be modified at any moment

Comment: @Tarek: Ok, would it be possible to make one single translation table `(object_id, object_kind, text_en, text_fr...)`, e.g. `1, subject, Chemie, Chemistry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a SQL `JOIN` for this.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.subject_en, ...
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.id = t1.subject_id)
```

A JOIN has a much better performane - you have only a single query which can be properly optimized by the database engine while doing a SELECT while iterating over the rows from the initial query would give you n+1 separate queries.